# Why does initial migration have dependencies?

Tags: django, database-migration

Without any prior migrations I have added custom *User* model in *core* app to enable custom authentication by following the documentation entry [Django 2.0 / Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)

Then I made migrations:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations

Migrations for 'core':
  core/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
```

At `0001_initial.py` migration class begins with:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length'),
    ]
```

I have looked through the official documentation [Django 2.0 / Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/) and this file obviously is an initial migrations since it has `initial = True`. But why does it have a whole chain of dependencies starting with [`0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.6/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length.py)? Did I made any mistake?

When migrations are ran this is the output:

```
$ python manage.py migrate  
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying core.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

When custom *User* model is omitted `0001_initial.py` starts with:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]
```

Additionally, I wasn't able to find a good explanation of what `migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` exactly does. What does it do and why is it even called "swappable_dependency"? It would be great if someone could demystify this part for me as well or point in right direction to explore on my own.

### Edit #1

Source code of custom *User* model.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email not defined.')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your custom user model.

Answer (score 5):

This is normal and expected behaviour - you still need the migrations from `django.contrib.auth` to be applied to your database.

If you [look at those migrations](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0001_initial.py)  they include various other models that are needed by the auth app - things like `Permission` and `Group`. The `User` model has fields that reference these other models, so you need migrations to have set those up first.

Because `User` is a swappable dependency, Django will ignore the `User` migrations in the `auth` app an use yours instead. But the migrations for all the other `auth` models will be applied from `auth.migrations`.

It is because of this dependency on the `auth` migrations that is [very difficult to change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) a custom user model after you've already set up your project:

> Due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models, the model referenced by `AUTH_USER_MODEL` must be created in the first migration of its app (usually called `0001_initial`); otherwise, you’ll have dependency issues.